# Create HEX attachment for Quality Notification

Tags: hex, attachment, abap, sap-basis

I have this piece of code to download the hex content of a file with import parameter file id. I want to insert a new attachment for a notification, but I don't know how to get started.

```
  METHOD GET_SINGLE_ATTACHMENT_CONTENT.

    " VARIABLES
    DATA: HEXCONT       TYPE TABLE OF SOLIX.
    DATA: DOCDATA       TYPE SOFOLENTI1.
    DATA: LV_LENGTH     TYPE I.

    " CHECK TO CONTINUE FUNCTION MODULE
    IF FILE_ID IS INITIAL. "type = SOFOLENTI1-DOC_ID.
      MESSAGE 'Document ID is empty.' TYPE 'E' RAISING DOC_ID_EMPTY.
    ENDIF.

    " GET BINARY CONTENT OF FILE
    CALL FUNCTION 'SO_DOCUMENT_READ_API1'
      EXPORTING
        DOCUMENT_ID    = FILE_ID
      IMPORTING
        DOCUMENT_DATA  = DOCDATA
      TABLES
        CONTENTS_HEX   = HEXCONT.

    IF SY-SUBRC <> 0.
      MESSAGE 'Error downloading file.' TYPE 'E' RAISING FILE_DOWNLOAD_ERROR.
    ENDIF.

    " CONVERT TO XSTRING
    LV_LENGTH = DOCDATA-DOC_SIZE.

    CALL FUNCTION 'SCMS_BINARY_TO_XSTRING'
      EXPORTING
        INPUT_LENGTH = LV_LENGTH
      IMPORTING
        BUFFER       = EV_RETURN "type XSTRING
      TABLES
        BINARY_TAB   = HEXCONT.

     IF SY-SUBRC <> 0.
      MESSAGE 'Error downloading file.' TYPE 'E' RAISING FILE_DOWNLOAD_ERROR.
    ENDIF.
  ENDMETHOD.
```

I've read about function modules like '**SO_DOCUMENT_INSERT_API1**' and it has the file information but not the file content (preferably hex content). Any idea on how to get started with this?

Comment: Sorry, but `SO_DOCUMENT_INSERT_API1` really has the file content parameter `CONTENTS_HEX`. Or do you use a very old SAP system?

Comment: I am also looking for the same answer. Could you maybe specify how to link it to the notification then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do something with the approach I used. Check this example below.

1. Start with parsing your data to hex
2. Insert the document with so_document_insert_api1
3. Link it to your notification with the fm binary_relation_create

   ---

   ```
   " TYPES
   TYPES: BEGIN OF TYPE_FILE,
            NAME    TYPE STRING,
            TYPE    TYPE STRING,
            QMNUM   TYPE QMNUM,
            USER    TYPE CHAR64,
            HEXCONT TYPE XSTRING,
          END OF TYPE_FILE.


   " VARIABLES AND OBJECTS 
   DATA: LT_RETURN             TYPE TABLE OF BAPIRET2.
   DATA: LT_HEXCONT            TYPE TABLE OF SOLIX.
   DATA: LS_DOCDATA            TYPE SODOCCHGI1.
   DATA: LS_DOCINFO            TYPE SOFOLENTI1.
   DATA: LS_FILE               TYPE TYPE_FILE.
   DATA: LV_DOCTYPE            TYPE SOODK-OBJTP.
   DATA: LV_FOLDER_ID          TYPE SOOBJINFI1-OBJECT_ID.
   DATA: LV_LENGTH             TYPE I.

   DATA: OBJ_NOTIF             TYPE BORIDENT.
   DATA: OBJ_ATTACH            TYPE BORIDENT.

   DATA: P_QMNUM               TYPE QMNUM.

   LV_FOLDER_ID = 'FOL40000000000004'.

   " CONVERT HEX CONTENT TO BINARY  
   CALL FUNCTION 'SCMS_XSTRING_TO_BINARY'
     EXPORTING
       BUFFER        = LS_FILE-HEXCONT
     IMPORTING
       OUTPUT_LENGTH = LV_LENGTH
     TABLES
       BINARY_TAB    = LT_HEXCONT.

   " SET VALUES  
   LS_DOCDATA-OBJ_DESCR = LS_FILE-NAME.
   LS_DOCDATA-OBJ_LANGU = 'E'.
   LS_DOCDATA-OBJ_NAME  = 'MESSAGE'.
   LS_DOCDATA-DOC_SIZE = XSTRLEN( LS_FILE-HEXCONT ).

   LV_DOCTYPE = LS_FILE-TYPE.

   UNPACK LS_FILE-QMNUM TO P_QMNUM.


   " CREATE ATTACHMENT  
   CALL FUNCTION 'SO_DOCUMENT_INSERT_API1'
     EXPORTING
       FOLDER_ID     = LV_FOLDER_ID
       DOCUMENT_DATA = LS_DOCDATA
       DOCUMENT_TYPE = LV_DOCTYPE
     IMPORTING
       DOCUMENT_INFO = LS_DOCINFO
     TABLES
       CONTENTS_HEX  = LT_HEXCONT.


   " CREATE LINK TO OBJECT (Notification)
   OBJ_NOTIF-OBJKEY   = P_QMNUM.
   OBJ_NOTIF-OBJTYPE  = 'BUS2038'.

   OBJ_ATTACH-OBJKEY  = LS_DOCINFO-DOC_ID.
   OBJ_ATTACH-OBJTYPE = 'MESSAGE'.

   CALL FUNCTION 'BINARY_RELATION_CREATE'
     EXPORTING
       OBJ_ROLEA    = OBJ_NOTIF
       OBJ_ROLEB    = OBJ_ATTACH
       RELATIONTYPE = 'ATTA'.


   " COMMIT 
   COMMIT WORK.
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another code-example in C# on how to add a GOS-Document to SAP using the the SAPNCO Connector for .NET.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Connect to SAP-System
            RfcDestination destination = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination("ABC");
            RfcRepository repository = destination.Repository;


            string pdfFilePath = "C:\\Dummy.pdf";
            byte[] pdfFileData = File.ReadAllBytes(pdfFilePath);

            // Create FUBA und get FolderId
            IRfcFunction SO_FOLDER_ROOT_ID_GET = repository.CreateFunction("SO_FOLDER_ROOT_ID_GET");
            SO_FOLDER_ROOT_ID_GET.SetValue("REGION", "B");
            SO_FOLDER_ROOT_ID_GET.Invoke(destination);

            IRfcStructure folderIdStructure = SO_FOLDER_ROOT_ID_GET.GetStructure("FOLDER_ID");

            // FolderId as String
            string folderId = $"{folderIdStructure.GetString("OBJTP")}{folderIdStructure.GetString("OBJYR")}{folderIdStructure.GetString("OBJNO")}";


            IRfcFunction SO_DOCUMENT_INSERT_API1 = repository.CreateFunction("SO_DOCUMENT_INSERT_API1");

            IRfcTable CONTENTS_HEX = SO_DOCUMENT_INSERT_API1.GetTable("CONTENTS_HEX");

            // Use a custom Extension-Method to split a byte-Array to chunks of 255 bytes per chnuk
            foreach (var chunk in pdfFileData.Split(255))
            {
                // for each chunk append a new line to the CONTENTS_HEX-table and append the chunk
                CONTENTS_HEX.Append();
                IRfcStructure LINE = CONTENTS_HEX.CurrentRow;
                LINE.SetValue("LINE", chunk);
            }

            // Set Document-Metadata, like FileName and FileSize
            IRfcStructure DOCUMENT_DATA = SO_DOCUMENT_INSERT_API1.GetStructure("DOCUMENT_DATA");
            DOCUMENT_DATA.SetValue("OBJ_NAME", "Dummy1.pdf");  // max 12 chars
            DOCUMENT_DATA.SetValue("OBJ_DESCR", "Dummy1.pdf");  // max 50 chars
            DOCUMENT_DATA.SetValue("DOC_SIZE", pdfFileData.Length);         // Filesize of the document


            // SET Import-Parameter
            SO_DOCUMENT_INSERT_API1.SetValue("FOLDER_ID", folderId);
            SO_DOCUMENT_INSERT_API1.SetValue("DOCUMENT_DATA", DOCUMENT_DATA);
            SO_DOCUMENT_INSERT_API1.SetValue("DOCUMENT_TYPE", "PDF");
            SO_DOCUMENT_INSERT_API1.SetValue("CONTENTS_HEX", CONTENTS_HEX);

            // Invoke SO_DOCUMENT_INSERT_API1
            SO_DOCUMENT_INSERT_API1.Invoke(destination);

            // Extract Output-Parameter after Function has been invoked
            IRfcStructure docINFO = SO_DOCUMENT_INSERT_API1.GetStructure("DOCUMENT_INFO");
            string docId = docINFO.GetString("DOC_ID");

            // BINARY_RELATION_CREATE_COMMIT will link the new document to an busines object
            IRfcFunction BINARY_RELATION_CREATE_COMMIT = repository.CreateFunction("BINARY_RELATION_CREATE_COMMIT");
            IRfcStructure OBJ_ROLEA = BINARY_RELATION_CREATE_COMMIT.GetStructure("OBJ_ROLEA");
            IRfcStructure OBJ_ROLEB = BINARY_RELATION_CREATE_COMMIT.GetStructure("OBJ_ROLEB");

            OBJ_ROLEA.SetValue("OBJKEY", "0010015511");     // Purchase-Request Number the new document should be linked to
            OBJ_ROLEA.SetValue("OBJTYPE", "BUS2105");       // BUS2105 means BANF-Documents

            OBJ_ROLEB.SetValue("OBJKEY", docId);            // DocumentID of the new created document
            OBJ_ROLEB.SetValue("OBJTYPE", "MESSAGE");

            BINARY_RELATION_CREATE_COMMIT.SetValue("OBJ_ROLEA", OBJ_ROLEA);
            BINARY_RELATION_CREATE_COMMIT.SetValue("OBJ_ROLEB", OBJ_ROLEB);
            BINARY_RELATION_CREATE_COMMIT.SetValue("RELATIONTYPE", "ATTA");

            // Invoke the BINARY_RELATION_CREATE_COMMIT function which does the Linking
            BINARY_RELATION_CREATE_COMMIT.Invoke(destination);
            var BINREL = BINARY_RELATION_CREATE_COMMIT.GetValue("BINREL");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Display Error-Message
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Is is necessary to open the contenct as hex?

You probably just want to read / write on a file. Try open `OPEN DATASET`

https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapset_dataset.htm

Comment: `OPEN DATASET` doesn't answer Yanana's question "insert a new attachment for a notification". I guess the requested answer is only about giving hints for using `SO_DOCUMENT_INSERT_API1`